# What is the name for unused memory

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks

When an application allocates memory but never frees it, we call it a memory leak.

However, if the application allocates memory, uses it for a short time and leaves it allocated for the rest of the execution time even though it is unused, and only frees it right before it finishes, it is not technically a memory leak, while still being a bug. Is there a name for this?

For example, using Qt in C++, I would mean:

```
int Foo::calculateSomething()
{
    MyClass *obj = new MyClass();
    obj->setParent(QCoreApplication::instance());
    if(obj->canDoSomething()) {
        return obj->doSomething();
        // obj is not deleted! It will still be destructed when the application finishes.
    } else {
        delete obj;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `obj` be destroyed when the function goes out of scope? Else though, I'm sure this would also be called a memory leak.

Comment: No, because it has been allocated in the heap, not in the stack (see the new). Besides that, it was set as a child of QCoreApplication::instance(). In Qt, when the application finishes, the application instance is destructed, and it destructs all its children. So obj would be freed, but only right before the application finishes.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the `obj->setParent(..)` call.
I would think that this would potentially be called a memory leak, if the object is not used by its parent (which it of course could be, depending on other code, and then not a leak at all). And if it is deleted, the parent would have a deleted object as a child, which would be a bad thing if accessed at another place. ;P

Comment: I would call that a memory leak too, at least a temporary one. Also, if you count memory that is released by the OS at the end of the process as "not leaked" then memory leaks are virtually impossible in many environments.

Comment: Well, in my case, the memory is actually freed by the application shortly before it finishes. So it means there is an instant when the application is still running (it hasn't returned to the OS yet) but it has already freed this memory.

Comment: @delnan: If a water pipe is leaking, there will be no limit to the amount of water that can flow through it, given enough time.  I tend to view the term "memory leak" the same way.  If, given enough repetitions of some action, there would be no upper bound on the ratio between the amount of memory consumed versus the amount that's "usefully employed", then I would say the action "leaks memory".  If only the first performance of an action consumes memory, I would generally not call that a memory leak.